# Configuring the env. variable HADOOP_STREAMING for RStudio

Tags: hadoop, rstudio, hortonworks-data-platform, rhadoop

I have installed RStudio 3.1 on Horton Hadoop.

Currently my Hadoop Streaming env variable is set using this path 
    export HADOOP_STREAMING=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar

I get the error when executing a simple mapreduce using RStudio

**Error in hadoop.streaming() : 
  Please make sure that the env. variable HADOOP_STREAMING is set**

Can anybody tell me what is the correct path for hadoop-streaming jar file ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where do you have your hadoop libraries installed, for instance if you're using the cloudera distribution, you can use the following inside R:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING = "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar")
```